# Truncate strings of a dataframe and group them together

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with codes that are written with one letter, two numbers and one decimal ('A09.9').  To treat them I need to group it by removing the decimal from the whole table.

So far I can't think of any form (the dataframe is 40000x100). But I have to simplify this:

```py
id code1 code2 code3 code4
0  A09.9 B25.3 A02.2  NaN
1  B29.3 J27.7 Z23.3 H35.2
2  C21.2 C03.5  NaN   NaN
```

to this:

```py
id code1 code2 code3 code4
0   A09   B25   A02   NaN
1   B29   J27   Z23   H35
2   C21   C03   NaN   NaN
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use apply on whole dataframe:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3])
```